# How to integrate cybersource payment gateway with wp form?

Tags: payment-gateway, cybersource

Is it possible to integrate cubersource payment gateway in wordpress using WP Form.
I need to initiate the payment when the amount is entered and submitted using wp form.
Is there any possiblilty do this without using the woocommerce feature?

The payment is getting done when we using the woocommerce by adding a product and checkout.
But I need the payment when I enter the amount in a form field, that time the form action is not working.